# Source Control list is blank after the installion TFS 2008 With SP

Tags: tfs

I have confidre a server for TFS. Following are installed on server step-by-step-

1. Windows 2003 Server with latest SP
2. SQL Server 2005 With Latest SP
3. .net framework with latest SP
4. WSS with latest SP
5. VSTS 2008 with SP
6. And Finally installed TFS with SP
   And we are not getting source control list in Visual Studio 2008-
   **Tools > Option > Source Control Plugin**  [list is blank]

is there any prblem, please help 
Thanks for Advance

Answer (score 1):

[Team Explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0ed12659-3d41-4420-bbb0-a46e51bfca86&displaylang=en) is missing from your list. It includes the Visual Studio integration packages that provide source control and all of the other integrated TFS features. You can also find it on the TFS install media.

Comment: Note that if you install Team Explorer after the VS service pack, you'll need to re-run the SP installer.